# Trying to create a scp command in bash

Tags: bash, server, tilde-expansion

I am trying to create a simple bash script that takes paths to directories as input and plugs them into an scp command.
The scp command looks like this:

```
scp user@server.com:/path/to/directory/on/server /path/to/directory/on/local/machine
```

I have made a simple bash function,

```
s2h () {
    local address_in_server="$1"
    local address_in_home="$2"
    echo "$address_in_server"
    echo "$address_in_home"
    scp user@server.com:$address_in_server $address_in_home
}
```

After running this script as
`s2h ~/testing/somefile.txt ~/Desktop`
The echo commands output

```
/Users/me/testing
/Users/me/Desktop/
```

This particular pathway, with /Users/me is meant for my local machine.
The problem is that bash is interpreting the "~" for the server as the "~" for my local machine. If I enter

```
s2h /home/myusername/testing/somefile.txt ~/Desktop
```

It works perfectly.

However, the command

```
scp user@server.com:~/testing/somefile.txt ~/Desktop
```

also works.

My question is, how do I get the bash script to understand what ~ means when calling a file from my server from an argument, and not translate it to the local meaning of ~?

Comment: Just invoke it like `s2h testing/somefile.txt ~/Desktop` -- the remote file will be found relative to your remote home directory.

Comment: hi @glennjackman. that did not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes to suppress local tilde expansion:

```
s2h "~/testing/somefile.txt" ~/Desktop
```

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus. This worked. Is there a way to do it in the bash function itself? want to make the user interface as simple as possible. i want it to work with ```s2h ~/testing/somefile.txt ~/Desktop```

Comment: It might help to replace in your code `"$1"` with `"${1/#$HOME/\~}"` to get back your `~`.